# Increasing speed of Fuzz Ratio

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am struggling to speed up this piece of code.

I have about 1 million strings in zz1 and 250,000 strings in a3. The strings in zz1 have errors in them and I would like to match it onto the one in a3, which has the highest ratio of fuzzy match.

I am happy with the results, but it takes about ~9 seconds to process one row in zz1. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
import csv
import string
import time
import sys
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
op=[]
for i in range(1,len(zz1)):
    num=zz1[i][1] 
    start2 = time.clock()
    forecast = []

    if not num in zz4 and zz5:

       for j in range (1,len(a3)):
           forecast.append(fuzz.ratio(num,a3[j][1]))

       if (max(forecast)>60):
           index=forecast.index(max(forecast))
           op.append(a3[index][1])

    elapsed2 = (time.clock() - start2)    
    print (i,elapsed2)
```

Comment: How significant are the errors in strings, and how large are the strings?  Can you give some examples?  Also, in your arrays, you access the second sub-element using ...[i][1] and ...[j][1] to retrieve the string to compare, so what is the structure of these arrays?  Your current approach will require 250 billion fuzz computations, in addition to the overhead for comparison, so speeding this up significantly will require a way to group your data to make the highest fuzz ratio easier to find, and that depends on the data you are checking.

Comment: So it is two csv files. One is zz1 and the other is a3. zz1 strings are names of different places around the world. Ex. 'MELBRNE REEF' but it has errors. a3 has two columns. One for the place, other for country. If a3 col 1 place has 'MELBOURNE REEF', zz1 should match to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data represents abbreviated strings rather than typos or other errors, you should be able to perform this operation by eliminating the easy choices.

Consider these two examples (I don't know how GRAND CANYON would be abbreviated, so this is just a guess to illustrate the point):

```
GRAND CANYON    -> GR CANYON
MELBOURNE REEF  -> MELBRNE REEF
```

There is no way GR CANYON could possibly relate to MELBOURNE REEF, so there is no need to test that.  Group by left prefix of the strings to codify this test, and you should see a very high hit rate since an abbreviation will normally preserve the first letter.

So, you only compare abbreviations that start with a "G" with the full names that also start with a "G", and "M" with "M", etc.

Note also that this doesn't have to provide a perfect match; you will maintain lists of unmatched strings and remove matches as you find them, so after you have compared the grouped strings and removed the matches, **your final list of unmatched items will be a very small subset of your original data that can be compared relatively quickly using your original brute-force approach**.

With just the first character, you reduce the number of strings to be compared in each list by a factor of 26, which reduces the number of comparisons by a factor of 26*26, that's 676 times faster!

Since perfect accuracy isn't necessary in the initial elimination steps, you could extend this grouping to more than just the first character for the first iteration, reducing the number of characters for each additional iteration until you reach zero characters.  With 2-character grouping, you reduce the number of items in each list to compare by 26*26, which reduces the total number of comparisons by 26*26*26*26, or from 250 billion down to about half a million comparisons.  With 3-character grouping, from 250 billion down to about 809.

By using this iterative approach, you will perform exponentially fewer fuzz operations, without losing accuracy.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. Though typos and other errors are present, this definitely speeds up most of it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much time this will save but this bit seems unnecessarily complicated:

```
for j in range (1,len(a3)):
    forecast.append(fuzz.ratio(num,a3[j][1]))

if (max(forecast)>60):
    index=forecast.index(max(forecast))
    op.append(a3[index][1])
```

Every time, you're making a new list with 250,000 elements in it, then you're checking that new list for the max element, then you're finding the index of that max element to retrieve the associated value from the original list.  It probably makes more sense to do something more like:

```
max_ratio = 0
match = ''
for a in a3:
    fr = fuzz.ratio(num,a[1])
    if fr > max_ratio:
        max_ratio = fr
        match = a[1]
if max_ratio > 60:
    op.append(match)
```

This way you're not creating and storing a big new list every time, you're just keeping the best match you find, replacing it only when you find a better match.

Comment: Tested your code. The speed increase is marginal. It is still averaging around 9 seconds for one iteration.